# Magento 2. Failed to submit module to Magento Marketplace. setup/config/application.config.php failed to open stream

Tags: php, module, magento2

I am unable to submit a new module or update a existing module in the **Magento Marketplace**.

For all modules/new versions, I get the error during the `Technical Review` at the `Installation & Varnish Test` stage. Error from `report.json`:

```
ERROR: [11] The command "php ./bin/magento module:enable --all --ansi --no-interaction" failed. Warning: require(/app/setup/config/application.config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php on line 78
returned non-zero exit status 11
```

The error occurs when executing different commands, not only for `php ./bin/magento module:enable --all --ansi --no-interaction`, but the error is always the same.

*I couldn't reproduce it locally on different versions of Magento, PHP and composer.*

*In my opinion, this looks like a problem with the environment in which the modules are tested.*

Comment: Yep, we get this too with our module - it only fails the polish test on PHP 7.4 and not on PHP 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, the problem was on Magento Marketplace side.

There is [news](https://magentocommeng.slack.com/archives/C7SL5CGDN/p1657755519323149) in [#marketplace](https://magentocommeng.slack.com/archives/C7SL5CGDN) Slack channel that the problem has been fixed:

> Hi all,
> The issue with “allow-plugins” in 2.3 is fixed now.
> Right now we are going to rerun tests for all affected submissions.
> Sorry for inconvenience and Thank You all for being patient.